# Array's address with dimension greater than 3

Tags: c, arrays, array-address

What is the *mathematical* function that gives the address of an array with more than 3 dimensions?
I already know that for an array `a[x][y]` with 2 dimensions is `(a (x * max_second_dimension + y) * byte)`

Comment: What you want to know ? Arrays name is its address irrespective of it's dimensions. Or you want to find the number of bytes in a 3 dimensional array ? Please make clear your question.

Comment: It's actually about the the internal mechanism of the language , that has to do with pointers, in order to find the address for a certain element of an array. I'm talking about the rest elements of the array, not about its first element. As far as I know, it is not sth that will help me in coding, I am just asking to understand how the language really finds the address for an array's element.

Comment: In short, consider you make an array of integers( 4 bytes ) . The compiler will put the array at 4 byte aligned address ( i.e multiple of 4). And each new member of array will be access by adding 4 to the start pointer. 

If the array you make is of chars (1 byte), then it will add 1 to the start address to access others.

Comment: Assume you have an array with 2 dimensions a[x][y] of integers and the address of a[0][0] is 5000. If you want to find the address of a[2][1], instead of adding 4 to 5000 until you reach a[2][1], you can simply use the mathematical function i wrote above. How can i find the same mathematical function for arrays with more dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array `a[N1][N2][N3]...[Nk]` the address of the element `a[i1][i2]...[ik]` would be equal to:

```
a +
+ i1 * (N2 * N3 * ... * Nk) +
+ i2 * (N3 * N4 * ... * Nk) +
+ i3 * (N4 * N5 * ... * Nk) +
...
+ i(k - 1) * Nk +
+ ik
```

Here what follows `i` and `N` are indexes (and so is `(k - 1)` in `i(k - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

let dimension of array be `lxbxhxg` which means array has declared using

```
data_type  array[l][b][h][g];
```

if you want address of cell at `array[x][y][z][a]` then it will be

```
array + (x*b*h*g + y*h*g + z*g + a) * sizeof(array[x][y][z][a])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a finite formula for array accessors of arbitrary dimensionality, which I will explain below.

But before, you should know that formal languages usually handle multi dimensional arrays in a grammar rule by accessing the topmost array over an index multiplied by the inner array size - which, in turn, results from a recursion. This may end up in another array, accessed by an index multiplied by the inner array size, with a specific offset and so on, until the accessed element is not an array. You should have a look at (e. g.) ANTLR, if you want to understand how formal languages work.

Of course, you can always find a specific expression, if you know the count of dimensions and the size of each dimension. For example: Let `a` be the address of the array, `s` an array of dimension sizes, `d` the number of dimensions, `c` an array of indexes (the coordinates in the space described by the array) and `e` the element size. The address would evaluate in pseudocode to:

`a + e * sum(i := 0, d - 1, c[i] * prod(j := i + 1, d - 1, s[j]))`

where `i`, `j` are loop variables and `sum`, `prod` are the big sum/product operator with corresponding lower limit in the first and upper limit in the second parameter. Please note, the empty product operator (last iteration) results to 1. I Haven't tested the above, but the principle should be clear. Sorra, but I don't seem to be able to post formulas in mathematical notation here.